# Непонятные действия над массивом

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Первая строка понятна — объявление и инициализация массива. Но вот что делает вторая строка?

```
short a[] = {1, 4, 8, 5};
(char *) (a + 3) - (char*) a;
```

Comment: На экзамене что ли сидите?

Comment: Проверьте с помощью компилятора. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он имеет вид: "Что будет в результате?"

Comment: @Majestio, переформулировал вопрос, сделав его полезнее для других.

Comment: @alexolut, результат адресной арифметики никуда не записывается, так что пробный запуск ничем не поможет.

Comment: @Arhad ну так надо значит его записать куда-то или вывести как есть.

Comment: Ничче не надо) Нужно просто расписать пошагово какие приведения производит компилятор. По сути - это и есть вопрос ТС'а.

Comment: То же самое, что и `sizeof(short[3])` (размер в байтах, точнее в `char` (которые не всюду 8-ми битные байты)) (и кстати, @Majestio, `movl $6, %ecx ;
 movl $6, %edx` оптимизатор вычисляет его на этапе компиляции)

Comment: Вторая строка ничего не делает и будет удалена компилятором (при включенной оптимизации).

Answer (score 11):

Разница двух указателей, указывающих на элементы одного массива, дает число элементов массива, расположенными между двумя указателями.

Или следуя стандарту C (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 9 When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of
>   the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object; **the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
>   array elements**

Это так называемая арифметика указателей.

Выражение `(a + 3)` имеет тип указателя `short *`и имеет значение адреса четвертого элемента массива `a` (элемента `a[3]`), то есть это указатель на последний элемент массива со значением 5. Выражение `a`  неявно преобразуется к указателю на первый элемент массива (элемент `a[0]`). Оба указателя приводятся к типу `char *`. То есть исходный массив интерпретируется как массив элементов с типом `char`. Поэтому значением выражения

```
(char *) (a + 3) - (char*) a
```

будет число байтов (или элементов типа `char`) между первым элементом исходного массива и четвертым элементом исходного массива, которое вычисляется по формуле `3 * sizeof( short )` Если `sizeof( short )` равно 2 (конкретное значение зависит от используемой платформы), то значением исходного выражения будет число 6. То есть перед последним элементом массива расположено 3 элемента, каждый из которых занимает 2 байта, или если интерпретировать массив как массив символов, как это имеет место в вышеприведенном выражении, то данная разница дает 6 элементов массива с элементами типа `char`, каждый из которых занимает 1 байт.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает различие, когда используются указатели `short *`, то есть указатели на исходные элементы массива, и когда элементы массива и, соответственно указатели на них, интерпретируются, как имеющие тип `char` и, соответственно, `char *`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    short a[] = { 1, 4, 8, 5 };

    size_t n = 0;

    for (short *p = a; p + n != a + 3; ) n++;

    printf( "n = %zu\n", n );

    n = 0;

    for (char *p = (char *)a; p + n != (char *)(a + 3); ) n++;

    printf("n = %zu\n", n);
}
```

Значение `n` после работы первого цикла будет равно 3, так как  `( a + 3 ) - a` равно 3, в то время как значение `n` после работы второго цикла будет равно `6`, так как `( char * )( a + 3 ) - ( char * )a`  равно `3 * sizeof( short )`.

Comment: было бы здорово, если бы ты привел тестовый код в выводом битовых значений при какждой "интерпретации". Имхо. Ну а так, пока - плюсую.